# How can I rename my files with datestamps in Aperture and keep them in order?

Tags: aperture, exif

Here's the problem:

If I shoot in continuous mode, I can have several images per second.  Aperture will happily import these and rename them with Date @ Time, but subsequently sorting either by version name or by file name will bring results up in mixed order for a given time stamp.

My camera supports the exif field subsectimeorginal and the field shows up in Aperture, but in Aperture, the field is always blank.  And there is no primitive to add this to to creating filenames anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to avoid direct import by Aperture.  Import them onto the disk using your camera software, or by using a card reader, or if you camera is suppored as a 'device' then direct copy in Finder.

Run the command:

```
exiftool  -d %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S '-filename<${datetimeoriginal}.${subsectimeoriginal}.%e'
```

This will format the filename as

```
2016-12-09_20-27-21.20.JPG  
2016-12-25_14-29-00.70.NEF
```

Exiftool can be downloaded from here:

http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Note that the subsecond time can be either a 2 or 3 digit number -- either centiseconds or milliseconds. My d7100 reports 2 digits, but the last one is *always* zero.  So internally it's using a decisecond timer.